# How do I delete a row if the user selected the row header?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row, delete-row

```
private void deleteRowButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (dataGridView1.SelectionMode == DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

So this is what I've tried. Now without the if statement it would work but it will delete the row on the selected cell. I don't want the user to accidentally delete it. How do I make it so that it can delete the row if the user selects the row header?

Like this:
[image: Row Header selected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `CellClick` event and test the value `e.ColumnIndex`:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == -1)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
}
```

Or you could subscribe to the `CellDoubleClick` event (using the same code) if you wanted to be a little more sure they didn't accidentally delete rows.

---

Since you have a button you want to use, I'd say try this:

```
if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == -1)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index);
}
```

But for some reason, it always returns 0 for `CurrentCell.ColumnIndex`, even if you selected the row header.

I suppose you could still subscribe to the `CellClick` event, but just store the current row index in a class-level variable that you can test in the button:

```
private bool isRowHeaderSelected = false;

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    isRowHeaderSelected = (e.ColumnIndex == -1);
}

private void deleteRowButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isRowHeaderSelected)
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
}
```

Comment: So I can't just use my button? Oh sorry I forgot to mention that it was a button to use. Just not familiar with CellClick event.

Comment: Actually I had to use bool as a field. I can't really make an var instead because it doesn't share it from method to method. What I also did was set the `isRowHeaderSelected` back to `false` every time the user clicks the delete button. This is because it will keep deleting unless they change a cell.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are writing winforms. Why don't you put the delete behind a messageBox? What datagridview event are you putting this under?

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == -1)
{
      DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you want to delete", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
      if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
      {
          dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
      }
}
```

Comment: Uhm it's a button. And it will only work if the user selected what it looks like on the highlighted part of my picture.

Comment: It is not a button, it's a special type of DataGridViewColumn. And there are many click events in a DGV, each with their own peculiarities. CellClick, CellDoubleClick, CellContentClick, CellMouseClick, CellMouseDoubleClick, MouseClick, MouseDoubleClick, and the list goes on